# How to Copy a number from a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to copy a section of a string, which lies between two fixed string sections. How to do it?

For example if the string is "...\abcd124\145@cvdf\efgh...". How to tell Mathematica to copy the number between abcd124\ and @cvdf, which is 145.

Here "..." means that the string continues on both sides, but may be different for each case.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Split the string on the backslash `\\`
2. Find the part that ends with `@cvdf`
3. Take the digits and convert to an expression, then use `FromDigits` to get the final number.

```
str = "...\\abcd124\\145@cvdf\\efgh...";

FromDigits@
 ToExpression[
  StringCases[
   SelectFirst[StringSplit[str, "\\"], StringEndsQ[#, "@cvdf"] &], 
   DigitCharacter]]
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how to convert single slash to double slash..

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To find a numeric value between the strings "abcd124\" and "@cvdf", we can use a named pattern and [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html). Assume the pattern happens only once within `string`.

```
string = "\\abcd124\\145@cvdf\\efgh";
ToExpression[First@StringCases[string, "abcd124\\"~~x:DigitCharacter..~~"@cvdf"->x]]
```

Get the same result using [`RegularExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) with this expression:

```
ToExpression[First@StringCases[string, RegularExpression["abcd124\\\\(\\d+)@cvdf"]->"$1"]]
```